# django-rest-framework: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not Deferred Attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating sample rest API using django-rest-framework,
I refereed the tutorial on there website https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/
I api is working fine when list and create new object but it throwing the exception during detail view(http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/1) of object.

I have added my code snippet below, Please let me know what wrong i am doing

**Models.py**

```
class Car(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    price = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CarsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
        fields = ('id', 'created', 'name', 'price')
```

**Views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def car_list(request):
"""
List all code cars, or create a new car.
"""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cars = Car.objects.all()
        serializer = CarsSerializer(cars, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CarsSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


@csrf_exempt
def car_detail(request, pk):
"""
Retrieve, update or delete a code cars.
"""
    try:
        car = Car.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Car.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = CarsSerializer(Car)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CarsSerializer(Car, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        Car.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cars/', views.car_list),
    path('cars/<int:pk>/', views.car_detail),

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to post exception.

But the problem is that you pass `class` and not instance of `class` to your serializer.

```
try:
    car = Car.objects.get(pk=pk)
except Car.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse(status=404)

if request.method == 'GET':
    serializer = CarsSerializer(car)  #  <-- car not Car (this type of error should be fixed everywhere)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

And in `Car.delete()` should be `car.delete()`

Comment: the exception <h1>TypeError
       at /cars/1/</h1>
  <pre class="exception_value">int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not &#39;DeferredAttribute&#39;</pre>
  <table class="meta">

Comment: this was the typo error but not sure why its give exception in as TypeError